# ListView Filter limit items with CollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ObservableCollection` and I want to display only 10 items of it in the `ListView`. How must the `Filter` look like?

```
CollectionView altView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(alteParkingListe.ItemsSource);
altView.Filter += //Show only 10 Items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the the [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property is as follows:

```
public virtual Predicate<object> Filter { get; set; }
```

Consequently, you need to supply a [`Predicate<object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0) which is a funtion that takes an argument of type `object` and returns a `bool`. The argument passed in is an item of the underlying collection. The filter predicate is called for each item. The return value indicates whether the item is preserved (`true`) or filtered out (`false`) of the view.

As you can see, the filter does not know anything about the underlying collection itself, only each item individually. Hence, there is no direct way of doing this with a filter.

Of course you can do **dirty** tricks like keeping the count of filtered items like this:

```
var itemsCount = 0;
altView.Filter = obj => ++itemsCount <= 10;
```

However, this is **not** a good solution and you need to ensure that `itemsCount` is reset each time.

---

Now for what you should do instead: Simply create another collection property and assign a filtered variant of your main collection, no collection view and no dirty tricks involved. Filtering can be done using Linq's [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0) method:

```
FilteredItemsCollection = AllItemsCollection.Take(10);
```

Comment: what do you mean to create a another collection property, so create a new collection?

Comment: @M.Nasiri Yes, exactly, a new collection that contains only the first 10 items.